# How to install r.mcda.electre on GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, installation, add-in

I have downloaded `r.mcda.electre` addon from the following link:

https://wingrass.fsv.cvut.cz/grass71/x86_64/addons/grass-7.1.svn/r.mcda.electre.zip

But I can not install it with the latest version of GRASS 7.3. When I click on the exe file I get the following message:

```
---------------------------
r.mcda.electre.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because libgrass_gis.7.3.svn.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I even tried to install the addon from the Grass GUI but I get the following message in GRASS 6.4.3:

```
ERROR: GRASS Addons <r.mcda.electre> not found
```

In GRASS 7.3 I get this error message:

```
Downloading precompiled GRASS Addons <r.mcda.electre>... Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn/scripts/g.extension.py", line 1729, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn/scripts/g.extension.py", line 1708, in main
    install_extension(source=source, url=url, xmlurl=xmlurl)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn/scripts/g.extension.py", line 679, in install_extension
    ret += install_extension_win(module)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn/scripts/g.extension.py", line 952, in install_extension_win
    outdev=outdev, directory=srcdir, tmpdir=TMPDIR)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn/scripts/g.extension.py", line 1093, in download_source_code
    f, h = urlretrieve(url, zip_name)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 345, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "C:\Program Files\GRASS GIS
7.3.svn\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (Sat Jun 04 09:05:16 2016) Command finished (1 sec)
```

This is my first experience with Grass.

Answer (score 1):

You should install addons with this command line inside of grass:

```
g.extension extension=r.mcda.electre svnurl=http://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass7
```

To run the module, from GRASS GIS you have to write "r.mcda.electre", fill the fields and press run button.